# No test were found

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, instrumentation

I am writing unit tests. I am extending the unit tests classes from ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2. I was running tests finely. But I don't know what happened. Now when I am running unit test are not running and it throws following exception

```
`No tests were found`
```

Please Help.

Here is my unit test class

```
public class UnitTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<TREResults> {
    TREResults trainingReinforcementResults;

    public UnitTest(Class<TREResults>activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        trainingReinforcementResults= getActivity();
    }
    public void testDownLoadTRESetting(){
    String userId = trainingReinforcementResults.getUS_USER_ID();
    Realm realm = 
    RealmSaveRestoreHelper.initRealm(trainingReinforcementResults);
    TRESettingsModelTest treSettings = 
    realm.where(TRESettingsModelTest.class).contains("userId", 
    userId).findFirst();`
    realm.beginTransaction();
    treSettings = realm.createObject(TRESettingsModelTest.class);
    treSettings.userId = userId;
    realm.commitTransaction();


}
    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }
```

Comment: No code no help

Comment: Do you use maven, or is this IDE-specific? What does the class look like?

Comment: @vegaasen please see my unit test class. I have edited my question add code

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `JUnit3`? Why`setup()` and `tearDown()` methods are `protected`? Shouldn't they be `public`?

Comment: I made it public but still same case. I have added following to gradle 

testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

Comment: This happens with Kotlin as well